# iPhone to iPhone Communication over long distance

Tags: objective-c, swift, iphone

I am new to iPhone app programing  and I am looking to make a simple app that can send and recieve a basic push notification. This notification would then trigger an action within the app when recieved. This cannot be sent over bluetooth or wifi as it will be over a long distance. How could I set this up?

Comment: firebase realtime database

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase Platform. Read more

1. https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database
2. https://firebase.google.com/products/in-app-messaging
3. https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging